# xarray and nparray, picking elements

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray

i switched from R to python just today, so sorry if my question maybe unprecise.

First: What i want to do/have:
I have a set of x and y coordinates, also an numpy array. Goal is to get the specific elements corresponding to the coordinates given by x and y:

```
import numpy as np
x=[0,1]
y=[0,1]
arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
arr[x,y]
```

The result is an array with 1 and 4, exactly what i want. So far so easy. But now i have a variable, lets call it var, with a type of xarray.core.variable.Variable
From it i want to extract single points like in the numpy example above. The way i found so far is

```
var = xr.DataArray.to_masked_array(var)
```

But now i got 2 arrays, one with the values and one with some suspicious boolean elements. So here is my question:

Is there a possibility to get the elements of an xarray simmilar to the numpy example, or, is there a fast way to convert the xarray.core.variable.Variable type to a numpy.ndarray?

Speed is of the essence, so no loops! Just for the background, each file i get the variable var from is
several GB in size and has a dimension of (125,6,824,848). So it would be nice getting rid of that boolean copy.

Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: Why does this use `.to_masked_array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Vectorized Indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#vectorized-indexing), which xarray supports through passing DataArrays as indexers.

Copying from the docs:

```
In [37]: da = xr.DataArray(
   ....:     np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)),
   ....:     dims=["x", "y"],
   ....:     coords={"x": [0, 1, 2], "y": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]},
   ....: )
   ....: 

In [38]: da
Out[38]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 4)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
  * y        (y) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'

In [39]: da[[0, 1], [1, 1]]
Out[39]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2)>
array([[1, 1],
       [5, 5]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
  * y        (y) <U1 'b' 'b'

In [40]: ind_x = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["x"])

In [41]: ind_y = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["y"])

In [42]: da[ind_x, ind_y]  # orthogonal indexing
Out[42]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2)>
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
  * y        (y) <U1 'a' 'b'

In [43]: da[ind_x, ind_x]  # vectorized indexing
Out[43]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2)>
array([0, 5])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
    y        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thanks alot :)

Comment: I don't understand why you have ind_x twice in the vectorised case, or how this is triggering different behaviour. I still need those y coords to be used too, so how do I use them if the syntax is identical to the orthogonal indexing case?